# Custom shape of Bootstrap Badge

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to change the shape of bootstrap badges. Not the default ellipse but a rectangle with rounded corners. What is the right way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the badge class like the following:

```
.badge {
    min-width: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like that...

```css
    .mynewbadge
    {
    
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        border-radius:4px; //modify it according to your need..
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        background:gray;
        color:white;
      text-align:center;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="mynewbadge">5</div>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful and was able to get the badge to look exactly like how it is wanted, if anyone else who are beginner like me may find the following useful

//class

```
 <span class="badge bg">[120]</span>
```

//css

```
.badge {
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

[image: //output]